# Xamarin Forms - Targeting .NET Standard

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I read this article a while ago:
https://blog.xamarin.com/net-standard-library-support-for-xamarin/

So, I converted all of our libraries from portable libraries to .NET Standard (1.4). I did this because the article says "This PCL now needs to be upgraded to target the .NET Standard Library, which can be found in the projects properties.".

However, I can't figure out how to build a Xamarin Forms project that targets .NET Standard. I cloned the Xamarin Forms samples, and opened up the MasterDetailPage project. I went in to the project properties and switched from portable to .NET Standard as per the instructions. Immediately, I get an error telling me that I need to opt in to NuGet 3.0 support. I'm fine with this, but how do I do it?

I found that if I remove the Xamarin Forms NuGet package, I am able to switch over to .NET Standard. However, once I have done this, I can't add the Xamarin Forms NuGet package back. It just keeps failing. Contrary to what the article says, I cannot add references to .NET Standard libraries. When I try to add a reference to existing .NET Standard libraries in my Solution, Visual Studio just gives me an error saying that the library is not compatible. Which version of .NET Standard should I be targeting for Xamarin Forms?

How do I get a .NET Standard library compiling with Xamarin Forms support?

Comment: Unfortunately Xamarin.Forms still only supports old PCL profiles through NuGet and is not compatible with `netstandard` in that respect. Speaking as of today, you'd need to install Xamarin.Forms via a proxy pcl project that is consumed by a netstandard project. There are other approaches, but ideally you should just wait until it's supported by netstandard to install easily. There's a few blogs on this like the one by Oren https://oren.codes/2016/07/09/using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard/

Comment: Please tell me you are joking! My god. I've spent so much time reorganizing all of our projects and getting them to compile for .NET Standard. Why did Xamarin announce in August last year that Xamarin supports .NET Standard if we can't compile for it?

Comment: I've tried following the link above, but it doesn't help in any way. I'm able to convert the Xamarin Forms project to .NET Standard 1.4, but I just get a bunch of compilation errors.

Comment: Xamarin supports it just fine. Xamarin Forms however does not quite yet. It will most likely make the netstandard 2.0 release.

Comment: It does support it. I've got it working. I will post my answer to my own question soon.

Comment: Using the word "support" here is subjective. You have to add an `imports` section and add the compatibility shim to "support" PCL profiles in netstandard 1.0->1.2. However I'm referring to `Xamarin.Forms` being supported in `netstandard` from a NuGet perspective as it only supports being installed in a PCL. This is why the compat shim was made: i.e. `Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility`. Ideally it would be nice to see `Xamarin.Forms` support at least `netstandard 1.3` as most libraries support that, but I believe the support will come in `netstandard 2.0` as it's a major release.

Comment: So given you want to support `netstandard 1.4`, I don't believe this would be possible given the shim only allows up to `netstandard 1.2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that you can get a .NET Standard project to reference the Xamarin Forms NuGet package, and therefore be able to leverage .NET Standard libraries in Xamarin Forms.

This article more or less explains how to do it. The trick is to import the portable framework in the project.json.
https://xamarinhelp.com/dot-net-standard-pcl-xamarin-forms/

If you can't get it working, here is a Git sample that does work.
https://github.com/adamped/XamarinForms.NetStandard.git

I was eventually able to target .NET Standard 1.4 without issues.

Comment: Is your project working all OK with .NetStandard 1.4? Which MVVM framework are you using? I'm planning to use MVVM Light, but I don't know if I'll be able to do it. Please share your experience, I'm in the same track.

Comment: Yes. It's working perfectly now. I'm not really using an MVVM framework. Our UI framework is a bit of a mish mash of patterns and the code is shared with Silverlight. I'd like to convert all the code to a single pattern like MVVM at some point, but nothing really fits the bill at this point.

Comment: given that project.json files are now dead, add the packagetargetfallback in the csproj is the way forward

Comment: Thanks. That will be useful when were able to upgrade to csproj 15.

Comment: Im guessing you dont use Sqlite. I'm having a hard time porting My Xamarin Forms PCL project which uses Sqlite to .Net Standard. I've tried EF Core too without success.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get Entity Framework core to work with Sqlite 

Comment: @MadhavShenoy, interesting. Does EF allow for ad hoc queries - i.e. SQL textual queries executed without prebuilding the data schema from the database?

Comment: Haven't tried that. I recreated my portable project as a .net standard library.

Comment: The SQLite.Net.Standard library that I mentioned has not been renamed to this https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/SQLite.Net.Standard

Answer (score 5):

If you wanna do it with the new Visual Studio 2017 release with csproj instead of project.json you can either use dotnet migrate CLI command or add/edit this code to your csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-win+net45+wp8+win81+wpa8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: The comment very useful as the links above are all talk about the old style project.json while in VS2017, only csproj is used